# How to add a new word to .dic/.aff files with pyhunspell?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, spell-checking, hunspell

I am using `pyhunspell` which is a python wrapper around `HunSpell`, a .dic/.aff files based spell checker, stemmer, word analyzer. 
The documentation for `pyhunspell` is [found here](https://code.google.com/p/pyhunspell/wiki/UsingPyHunspell). Unfortunately, the doc pages do not demonstrate **how to add new words to the dictionary**/extend the dictionary **via Python script**. However the [source code](http://pyhunspell.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hunspell.c) of `pyhunspell` contains an `add()` function, but unlike the other functions, there is no explanation for `add()`, e.g. what arguments this function is expecting. Has anybody managed to call this function before and could write me an example how to use this `add()` function?

Here is the C source for the function(s) I would like to call, but my C is too limited to understand what is going on here.

```
static PyObject *
HunSpell_add(HunSpell * self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *word;
    int retvalue;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &word))
        return NULL;
    retvalue = Hunspell_add(self->handle, word);

    return Py_BuildValue("i", retvalue);
}

static PyObject *
HunSpell_add_with_affix(HunSpell * self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *word, *example;
    int retvalue;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ss", &word, &example))
        return NULL;
    retvalue = Hunspell_add_with_affix(self->handle, word, example);

    return Py_BuildValue("i", retvalue);
}
```

Thank you.

---

UPDATE:

As hinted by @RedX I have tried calling the add() function with 1 or 2 arguments. Here are my findings:

As an example, I use the hu_HU (Hungarian) dictionary files (.dic and .aff), which is the one I would need to extend with specialized domain vocabulary for an application. To keep the example transparent to English speakers I have chosen a name (McNamara) which is not yet included in the hu_HU dictionaries. Since Hungarian is a morphologically very rich language, I need to care about the declination of the word, otherwise the stemming of the word will not work.

`McNamara` follows the same declination pattern as `Tamara` which is already recognized and can be stemmed correctly, e.g. for the word Tamarával ("with Tamara")

```
import hunspell

hobj = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/hu_HU.dic', '/usr/share/hunspell/hu_HU.aff')
stem = hobj.stem("Tamarával")
print(stem)
```

will output ['Tamara'], which is correct.

Now, if I try to call add() with the new word and the example:

```
import hunspell

hobj = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/hu_HU.dic', '/usr/share/hunspell/hu_HU.aff')
hobj.add("McNamara", "Tamara")
```

This will throw me a `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. And yet the suggestion by @RedX based on the C code seems logical.

Also if I call the add("McNamara") with a single argument, it only seems to add the new word for the current session, not for the next run of the script, e.g.:

```
hobj.add("McNamara")
print(hobj.spell("McNamara"))
```

This prints `True`, but the next time I run the script with only the last line, it will return a `False`.

Comment: Have you tried `add(word)` and `add(word, example)`? I'd say those should work. I'm just not sure how to tell hunspell which dictionary to add it to when using multiple.

Comment: @RedX Yes, based on the C code that seems absolutely logical, however it doesn't really work. Please check my updated question description (from the UPDATE line).

Comment: Looking at `man 3 hunspell` there does not seem to be a way of adding custom words with declination through the programattic interface. [`man 4 hunspell`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/4/hunspell/) shows how to generate a dictionary file.

Comment: @RedX This is a real "madness" the author of hunspell has a confusingly similar other project called "magyar ispell" and the documentations of these projects is sporadically spread over a number of websites and repositories. My best option seems to be manually extending the .dic and .aff files, latter seems to be a stack of garbled text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a detail in the C binding code. There are two different functions.

- The fisrt one is `add` and it adds a word into the currently used dict (only for runtime). It allows you to call `spell` on it.
- The second one is `add_with_affix` and it allows you to add a word in the dict and to copy flags from another one.

For example (working on a french dict):

```
>>> hf.spell("pipoteuse")
False  # word not in the dict
>>> hf.stem("pipoteuses")  # try some classic plural stem
[]  # no stem
>>> hf.analyze("pipoteuse")
[]  # no analysis
>>> hf.add_with_affix("pipoteuse", "chanteuse")
0  # 0 = succesful operation
>>> hf.spell("pipoteuse")
True   # word in the dict now
>>> hf.analyze('pipoteuse')
[b' st:pipoteuse is:fem is:sg']  # flags copied from "chanteuse", is feminin singular and stem is itself (like chanteuse)
>>> hf.stem("pipoteuses")
[b'pipoteuse']  # now stem the plural of this fake word
```

Some link updates on the way:

- New repository is here: https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell
- Last version (0.4.0) has now some pydoc for all functions. (No online doc for all though)